# Get facebook check ins via FQL or Graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

So what I need to achieve is to get all facebook check ins for certain user (myself, or my friend).

According to FB documentation over FQL that should be simple, for example:

```
SELECT author_uid, tagged_uids, target_id, timestamp FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = me()
```

But atm I'm not getting any errors, only empty data array in return, but obviously I have a lot of facebook check-ins also, if I tried with different author_uid's (friends of mine, all permissions are granted) I'm getting the same response.

For me this is not logical and if I'm doing something wrong here I would realy appreciate if u can point me in right direction ;)

Comment: Do you have valid access token ?

Comment: Yes, I granted all permissions in api explorer

Comment: Then I guess you also checked for "user_status" permission as described in the docs, right? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/#permissions If so, it should work, at least it does for me

Comment: can u put somewhere (pastebin, pastie) the response which u are getting for query above (I granted all permissions by the way) ?